# Swift Searching for key words in a string

Tags: swift

I am creating a simple chat bot using swift 3 in Xcode 8, and have been looking for a way to search for a specific word in a string.

For example:

If the user inputs "I would like to have a cup of coffee please."

The program then checks the string for the word "coffee" then finding "coffee" in the string it then returns bool.

I know that you can do this in python:

```
phrase = "I would like to have a cup of coffee please."
if "coffee" in phrase 
    print('hi there')
```

How would you do this in swift 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4...

Using `contains(_:)` (See [String's ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893238-contains) in Swift 4):

```
let haystack = "I would like to have a cup of coffee please."
let needle = "like"
print(haystack.contains(needle))
```

---

Swift 3..<4

Using `range(of:..)` (See [String's ref](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/String/#func-range-of_options_range_locale_) in Swift 3):

```
let haystack = "I would like to have a cup of coffee please."
let needle = "like"

if let exists = haystack.range(of: needle) {
    // Substring exists
}
```